# Why express.Router() while separating routes

Tags: node.js

1. I have gone through express document in that  i have learn about
   Router() and express.Router(). so my question is  i have separated
   my all routes from main app and created different folder there i did
   not create any router object(var router express.Router()) for
   routing  to specific path still it's working fine. So i want to know
   why this Router class is necessary ?

   see, This is main app file,

   'use strict'; const startUpDebugger=require('debug')('app:startUp');
   const dbDebugger=require('debug')('app:db'); const express =
   require('express'); const app = express(); const
   moragan=require('morgan'); const helmet=require('helmet'); const
   config=require('config'); const courses=require('./routes/courses');
   const home=require('./routes/home'); app.use(helmet());
   app.set('view engine','pug'); app.set('views','./view');
   app.use(express.json()); app.use('/api/courses',courses);
   app.use('/',home);

   console.log(`Node enironment variable: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
   console.log(`Application name : ${config.get('name')}`);
   console.log(`mail server : ${config.get('mail.host')}`);

   if(app.get('env')==='development'){
       app.use(moragan('tiny'));
       startUpDebugger("******Morgan enabled*******") }

   const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; app.listen(port);

   console.log(`Api Node running on port ${port}`);

   This is my courses.js which is my route file

   const express=require('express'); const app=express

   const courses=[{"id":1,"course":"course1"},
                  {"id":2,"course":"course2"},
                  {"id":3,"course":"course3"},
                  {"id":4,"course":"course4"}]

   app.route('/posting').post((req,res)=>{
       console.log(req.body);
       courses.push(req.body)
       res.status(201).send(courses);  }).put((req,res)=>{
        res.send("Successfully put message")  })  app.get('/sub/:id',(req,res)=>{
       res.status(200).send(req.params);  })

   module.exports=app;

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but if i am getting you right:-

If your app is really simple, you don't need routers.

```
//you can just invoke express constructor and use it   
const app=express() 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('root')
}) // app.get,app.post and so on
```

in your main app file.

But as soon as it starts growing, you'll want to separate it into smaller "mini-apps", so that it's easier to test and maintain, and to add stuff to it. You'll avoid a huge main app file  :) .
so here you need to make another file for routes and have to invoke express.Router() class and use it 
like:

```
//route.js
const Router=express.Router()

    // middleware that is specific to this router
    router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
      console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
      next()
    })
    // define the home page route
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Birds home page')
    })
    // define the about route
    router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
      res.send('About birds')
    })
```

And import this file into the main app file and pass it to middleware to use

```
app.use('/',require('./routes/routes.js'))
```

and comparing to express() object the express.Router() object is light weight

Comment: Thanks for your reply ....yes so as you said using express.Router class you can separate and maintain your routes but that mainance of routes in separate file can be possible by only express app also by importing file in main app.
So express.Router() object is only used because it  is light weight?

Comment: **It's mostly about code organization / maintainability and scoping middleware. And Its about not packing unrelated code together.** There is a good article at [https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4 ]  which describes the differences and what can be done with routers.

Comment: yes but that can be possible using only express app also then why Router()?

Comment: We use a router instead of the app object for a variety of reasons:
**1.**  Code modularity. A module creates it's own router, sets up a bunch of routes on it and then exports the single router which the caller can then add to the current app.   
**2.**  You have a bunch of routes all with the same prefix and find it cleaner to set up a router for that common prefix and then just put the routes on that router without having to specify the prefix in every one of them.
**+check next cooment too**

Comment: **continue..........**    **3.**  To create a set of routes that share the same middleware processing, but other routes in your app do not share that middleware processing. In this case, you create the router, put some middleware on it and then define routes on that router. The middleware will only fire for routes that are routed to this router.